# What to be aware of when reporting to multiple managers?

Tags: manager, people-management

As someone who has never been in a role where I'm managed by two different people, are there any pitfalls or common issues that I should be aware of?

There is a position opening up soon for which I am told I am the prefered internal candidate.  One thing that concerns me a bit is that I am told that the line manager for this position is the operations manager but the functional manager would be the plant manager.

Google searching "functional manager vs line manager" yeilds some conflicting information but generally the answers fall along the lines of your line manager will be handle things like attendance and compensation whereas your functional manager will handle your responsibilities within the company.  I plan on clarifying this during the interview anyway but I would like to know if this aligns with other people's experience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34041/discussion-between-lilienthal-and-myles).

Comment: Can't chat, firewall blocks it :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have spent a good chunk of my career in those circumstances. Right now I have a line manager and work for at least ten different functional managers, so it can get complicated.

The things to look out for are:

- Make sure it is clear which of the two (or more) sets work
  priorities. In your case the Plant Manager probably is the supervisor
  for the Ops manager, so the priority setting is easier than when they
  are peers.
- Make sure there is no bad blood between the two people or you could
  get caught in the middle.
- Make sure the line manager knows what your accomplishments are
  through the year and be forceful in bragging about them in any
  self-assessment you may write. If you don't then you likely will not
  be his highest rated employee because he doesn't know what you did.
- Discuss with the line manager how often he needs to hear from you as
  you will spend most of your time dealing with the functional manager.
  You don't want resentment because he gets too much irrelevant junk
  from you or because he never hears from you except when you want to
  take vacation.
- When you want to take scheduled vacation, talk to the functional
  manager first to make sure the dates are OK and make sure the line
  manager knows the functional manager is aware of the dates. For sick
  leave, inform both or inform the line manager and ask him to pass the
  information up depending on how the line manager wants to handle it.

it can be great to work in these circumstances but it takes solid communication skills on your part to make sure both are getting the level of information from you that they want.

Answer (score 4):

I've been in this situation a couple of times in my career - thankfully it hasn't been a problem. The biggest risk in this sort of situation is that you get pulled in two different directions by your two managers - if they both say "X should be your top priority item" for different values of X, you have to know which one to work on. The way I've handled that is to establish the one of the managers is "first among equals" and gets the final say in the short term; in the longer term, if your managers continue to disagree on something, it's up to them to sort it out between themselves.

Other than that, take the positives of the situation: you've got two people you can ask for advice on any situation, two people to learn from and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in this situation a bit as a computer person working in the field for non computing companies.  It is typically better to have a higher level person that sees the big picture as your line manger.

I was managed centrally as part of a skill pool.  I kind of got shafted as I did not have someone that saw me day to day to argue my worth when it came ranking and rating.  I did not ask for this but they decided to have distributed staff rated and ranked within the functional manager and across the board we got screwed.  It was forced ranking and they wanted their engineers to get the best ratings and we were disposable to them.  So it went back to central rating and ranking the next year and they agree to ignore a low ranking if you had a higher on either side.  But when I came back after three distributed assignments it worked way better for me with a breadth of experience even if I took some minor hits in ranking.

The point is managing you as an asset and managing your day to day tasks are different and some times best to be managed by different people.